# How can I export an entire SQL Server table to CSV, when the table contains an Image column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, export, binary-data

I have a SQL Server table with the following design:

[image]

I need to export this entire table to a CSV file, with the data looking like this in plain-text format:

[image]

When I use the Import/Export wizard in SSMS, I get the following results in the CSV:

[image]

As you can see, this doesn't contain the actual binary data from the Image columns.
Instead, it just says `System.Byte[]` in plain-text, in each row.

In the past I've copy/pasted the text directly from the SSMS results window, into notepad, to manually produce the CSV.
However this table is so long, and the images are so large, that my computer runs out of memory if I try this now.

There must be a method to export the binary data into a CSV, in `0x1234ABCD` format (hex).
How could I accomplish this?

Comment: Try converting the binary value to a hex string with a `SELECT` query like `SELECT SS,CONVERT(varchar(MAX), PhotoMen, 1) AS PhotoMen, CONVERT(varchar(MAX),Thumbnail , 1) AS Thumbnail FROM dbo.PhotosMen;`

Comment: @DanGuzman That results in an error: `Explicit conversion from data type image to varchar(max) is not allowed` EDIT: fixed it by converting to `varbinary(max)` first.

Answer (score 1):

if you are a developed you can create small C# app Useing Base64 encoding for your binary data. It converts any binary data into readable string. The code is as following

Encode

```
public static string Base64Encode(string plainText) 
{
    var plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
    return System.Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes);
}
```

Decode

```
public static string Base64Decode(string base64EncodedData) 
{
  var base64EncodedBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(base64EncodedData);
  return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(base64EncodedBytes);
}
```

Comment: This is very useful information. It's not what I'm looking for in my situation, but this Base64 solution could be helpful to other people reading this.

Answer (score 0):

Following the advice in Dan Guzman's comment, I created a new view with the following query:

```
CREATE VIEW vwPhotosMen AS
    SELECT SS,
           CONVERT(varchar(max), CONVERT(varbinary(MAX), PhotoMen, 1), 1) AS PhotoMen,
           CONVERT(varchar(max), CONVERT(varbinary(MAX), Thumbnail, 1), 1) AS Thumbnail
    FROM dbo.PhotosMen
```

The SSMS Export Wizard was then able to export the data correctly from this view, to a plain-text CSV file.

Comment: The image type has been deprecated for 15 years so I assumed you were already using `varbinary(MAX)`.

Comment: @DanGuzman Haha yeah .... let's just say, I'm migrating some VERY old data ...